# Top 1 Item from the List in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following scenario

I am getting Output like this

```
Month      Product Name  Amount   
Jan-2014   A-Prodcut     50
Jan-2014   B-Product     45
Jan-2014   C-Product     55 
Feb-2014   A-Prodcut     60
Feb-2014   B-Product     48
Feb-2014   C-Product     80
```

I want Output like this :

```
 Jan-2014   C-Product     55
 Feb-2014   C-Product     80
```

I want top product from each month How to achieve this

Here is my query

```
        ;With cte as
        (
            SELECT @EndDate AS TheMonth, 0 as [Counter] 
            UNION ALL

            SELECT DATEADD(mm,-[Counter] -1,@EndDate), Counter + 1 AS TheMonth
            from cte
            WHERE DATEADD(mm,-[Counter] -1,@EndDate) >= @StartDate
        )

SELECT                      
    left(DATENAME(MM,TheMonth),3) +'-'+ cast(year(TheMonth) as varchar) AS [Month-Year],
    ISNULL(IM.product_name,'N/A') as 'Product Name',
    isnull(sum((ism.selling_price * siim.qty) + (((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * siim.qty))/100))),0) AS Amount
FROM
    cte
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Master AS SM on MONTH(invoice_date) = MONTH(TheMonth)
                                                                        AND YEAR(invoice_date) = YEAR(TheMonth)   
                                                                        AND sm.is_approved = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master AS SIIM ON SM.sell_order_no  = SIIM.sell_order_no
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Inventory_Master AS IM ON SIIM.product_id = IM.product_id                
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Tax_Master AS TM ON TM.tax_id = SIIM.tax_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Inventory_Selling_Master AS ISM ON ISM.selling_product_id = SIIM.selling_product_id  
GROUP BY
    IM.product_name,
    TheMonth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Row_number() in the select query ie.

```
SELECT MONTH, PRODUCT_NAME, AMOUNT
FROM (
   SELECT MONTH, PRODUCT_NAME, AMOUNT,
   ROW_NUMBER ( ) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY Month order by amount Desc) AS RANK
     )
WHERE RANK = 1
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: it should be `order by amount desc` to get the one with highest amount for each month.

Comment: hehe.. forgot that.. sorry :P

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT [Month-Year], [Product Name], Amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY  [Month-Year] ORDER BY Amount DESC) as rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT                      
            left(DATENAME(MM,TheMonth),3) +'-'+ cast(year(TheMonth) as varchar) AS [Month-Year],
            ISNULL(IM.product_name,'N/A') as 'Product Name',
            isnull(sum((ism.selling_price * siim.qty) + (((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * siim.qty))/100))),0) AS Amount
        FROM
            cte
            LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Master AS SM on MONTH(invoice_date) = MONTH(TheMonth)
                                                                                AND YEAR(invoice_date) = YEAR(TheMonth)   
                                                                                AND sm.is_approved = 1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master AS SIIM ON SM.sell_order_no  = SIIM.sell_order_no
            LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Inventory_Master AS IM ON SIIM.product_id = IM.product_id                
            LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Tax_Master AS TM ON TM.tax_id = SIIM.tax_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Inventory_Selling_Master AS ISM ON ISM.selling_product_id = SIIM.selling_product_id  
        GROUP BY
            IM.product_name,
            TheMonth
    ) a
)b
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY` is a way to go in theese situations.

So your SELECT would be like this:

```
;With cte as
(
    SELECT @EndDate AS TheMonth, 0 as [Counter] 
    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(mm,-[Counter] -1,@EndDate), Counter + 1 AS TheMonth
    from cte
    WHERE DATEADD(mm,-[Counter] -1,@EndDate) >= @StartDate
)
SELECT                      
    left(DATENAME(MM,TheMonth),3) +'-'+ cast(year(TheMonth) as varchar) AS [Month-Year],
    'Product Name', Amount
FROM
    cte
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 
                   ISNULL(IM.product_name,'N/A') as 'Product Name',
                   isnull(sum((ism.selling_price * siim.qty) + 
                   (((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * siim.qty))/100))),0) AS Amount
        FROM  RS_Sell_Order_Master AS SM    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master AS SIIM 
                ON SM.sell_order_no  = SIIM.sell_order_no
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Inventory_Master AS IM 
                ON SIIM.product_id = IM.product_id                
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Tax_Master AS TM 
                ON TM.tax_id = SIIM.tax_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Inventory_Selling_Master AS ISM 
                ON ISM.selling_product_id = SIIM.selling_product_id  
       WHERE MONTH(invoice_date) = MONTH(TheMonth) AND YEAR(invoice_date) = YEAR(TheMonth) AND sm.is_approved = 1
       ORDER BY Amount DESC
   ) x
GROUP BY
    'Product Name',
    TheMonth
```